# Difference in Latent Variables and Nuisance Parameters

Tags: probability

In my limited knowledge of statistics, I am confused between the meaning of Latent Variables and Nuisance Parameters.

Here is my current understanding:

- Sometimes the variance parameters in a regression model (or the overdispersion parameters) are considered as Nuisance Parameters because we are not directly interested in estimating them
- In a Gaussian Mixture Model, the weights of each Gaussian Mixture are called Latent Variables because we do not observe them directly (although this point somewhat confuses me because we dont observe any parameter directly, latent or non-latent ... all we observe is data)

From an estimation perspective:

- We remove the nuisance parameters (via marginalization, factorization) because they can bias the estimates. I don't fully understand this, but I think it has to do with degrees of freedom, MLE produces biased variance estimates (in complex regression models, we can not a priori know the correction factor needed to remove the bias). Later, if required, we estimate the variance parameters using a more complicated form of MLE called RMLE
- We remove the latent variables (again via marginalization) ... because they make the optimization problem easier? (i.e. reduce the dimensionality of the function being optimized) Is this the only reason we remove latent variables? Or is there some other reason ? (ex: the estimation of latent variables is biased?)

From here, it looks like these concepts are almost interchangeable: A nuisance parameter is latent and a latent variable is a nuisance. They both complicate the estimation process for similar reasons and we try to remove them through clever math tricks (e.g. marginalization).

I feel I am missing something here - any one have hints?

Answer (score 1):

In the non-Bayesian paradigm, latent variables are random variables whereas nuisance parameters are fixed (unknown) parameters. We use latent variables to model random, unobservable effects whereas nuisance parameters are just the subset of the parameters that we don't want to perform inference for, yet they are needed to correctly model the phenomenon.

Indeed, having a lot of parameters in a model can make the joint estimate less robust. In some types of models, the parameter space grows *with* the sample size, so collecting more data doesn't alleviate the problem. Profiling or factoring out nuisance parameters (in MLE) or integrating them out (Bayes) is a way to addres it in many cases.